# How to release Array objects in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsarray

An array has contains multiple objects.If we call **removeAllObjects**  method, Whether objects will 
be released which in an array or we have release manually.

Comment: Some of your questions have answers; it may be worthwhile to find some that you can mark accepted.

Answer (score 3):

Sending an `NSArray` that message will cause it to release all its pointers. You don't need to release what you put in there yourself, unless you have your own pointers to those objects elsewhere.

Comment: Yeah, but I was answering under the assumption that OP is dealing with the contents as opposed to the array itself. I could be wrong though, just taking a stab in the dark...

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to remove all objects before you release. When an NSMutableArray is dealloc'd, it releases all of the objects in contains automatically.

More [click](http://forums.macrumors.com/archive/index.php/t-579964.html)  here

Answer (score 0):

You should do this to release your array. Better to release it this way rather than autoreleasing the array

```
[YourArray release];
YourArray = nil;
```

If you just want to get rid of the data and dont want to release the array then you can simply do:

```
YourArray = nil;
```

It is better to release array using `[YourArray release]` statement then declaring it as `autorelease` in declaration.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: @Stephen: Thanks for your help. I have corrected my mistake. Is it fine now?

Comment: While this code works, it is not an answer to the OP's question. There are plenty of reasons why one would want to just empty the array, instead of getting rid of it like you're doing.

Comment: @Douwe Maan: Yeah but in the question Gnanavadivelu has written how to "release" array objects and hence I have discussed even release portion in case he wants to completely get rid of the array. I have edited my answer looking at your perception towards it. Thanks for the help though :)